# jquery click is not working on element with data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a click event on li element but it's not working.

Following is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <ul>
        <li class="select userlist" data-userid="172" data-type="employer" data-jobid="218">
            <div class="cl-left">
              <div class="image"> <img src="userimages/75541c25341c9d7f88012c77f91b495578c46925.jpg" class="userimage"><span class="onlinestatus on"></span> </div>
            </div>

          </li>
       </ul>
    </body>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var not_yet_assigned = 172;
        $('.userlist[data-userid="'+not_yet_assigned+'"][data-jobid="218"]')[0].click();
        $('.userlist[data-userid="'+not_yet_assigned+'"][data-jobid="218"]').click();
        $('.userlist[data-userid="'+not_yet_assigned+'"][data-jobid="218"]').trigger('click');
        $('.userlist[data-userid="'+not_yet_assigned+'"][data-jobid="218"]').on('click', function(){
            alert('clicked');
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's missing the `li` parent tag, it must be inside a `ul` or `ol` list

Comment: @RicardoPontual: That's certainly true, but the element would show up *somewhere* in the DOM (the browser may auto-create a `ul` for it).

Comment: Your last one, the `.on` with the function, [works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/n7ztwgmf/). What is the purpose of the first three?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, the browser will show the `li` element, but never "auto-create" an `ul` tag, see your fiddle example :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual: Oh, you can't say "never" in this situation -- it's entirely up to the browser what to do when presented with patently-invalid markup. :-) (That said: Auto-generating elements isn't as popular as it once was...)

Comment: i've never noticed that a tag have auto-generated by the browser, but, as we're talking about browsers everything is possible, so I agree with you that "never" is a too strong word for a browser :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've understood is you want to trigger click event through jQuery and for that you need to define the `click` function before triggering it like this

```html
<html>
    <head>
            <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <li class="select userlist" data-userid="172" data-type="employer" data-jobid="218">
            <div class="cl-left">
              <div class="image"> <img src="userimages/75541c25341c9d7f88012c77f91b495578c46925.jpg" class="userimage"><span class="onlinestatus on"></span> </div>
            </div>

          </li>
    </body>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var not_yet_assigned = 172;
         $('.userlist[data-userid="'+not_yet_assigned+'"][data-jobid="218"]').on('click', function(){
            alert('clicked');
        });
        $('.userlist[data-userid="'+not_yet_assigned+'"][data-jobid="218"]')[0].click();
        $('.userlist[data-userid="'+not_yet_assigned+'"][data-jobid="218"]').click();
        $('.userlist[data-userid="'+not_yet_assigned+'"][data-jobid="218"]').trigger('click');
       
    });
    </script>
</html>
```